# Move Layout Up when Soft Keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I have login page with Email Id ,Password & LOGIN button. Right now when any one of the Edit Text gain focus then system keyboard hides my Login button. I want to push my layout above when keyboard appears keeping LOGIN button above of keyboard.

P.S I've tried all solution like 
adjust Pan|adjust Resize, adjust Pan,adjust Resize"

in manifest as well as in Java code

But none of thing worked for me.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/newl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_clock"
    android:id="@+id/clock"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Timetracker"
    android:fontFamily="LucidaGrande"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/tt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/clock"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/tt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:drawablePadding="12dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:fontFamily="Sans Serif"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lock"
        android:drawablePadding="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"

        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="LOG IN"

        android:id="@+id/log"
        android:textColor="#D04045"/>



</LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: remove your outer linear layout inside scroll view and use relative layout instead..

Comment: @janki I've changed Linear layout to Relative layout but still problem persists

Comment: send here your updated code. becoze in my case it workes fine

Comment: @janki I've updated my question with new code. Scroll view is wrapped under Relative layout Please check.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use android:fillViewport="true" on the ScrollView.

and with this you can also use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

try this,
Add the below line in your manifest file,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

For example,

```
<activity android:name=".Game"  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

    </activity>
```